# Number of ways to select the elements of an array such that their sum is greater than a number K

Tags: arrays, combinations

You are given an array of size (N) with entries (P_i). You are allowed to pick exactly one element from the array
each day. Also, at the end of each day, the value of all the elements of the array is reduced to (50\% ) of the value at
the start of the day. This means if an entry in the array on a specific day is  (P_i), then it is reduced to    (P_i/2) at the
end of the day.

Note

1. The division performed is the integer division
2. Any element once picked can not be picked again.

You are also provided with (Q) queries.
Each query contains a number (K_i). You have to determine the number of ways to select the elements of the array
such that the sum of values that are selected is /(ge K_i ).

Input format:

First line: (T) denoting the number of test cases
For each test case:

First line: An integer (N) denoting the size of the array
Next line: (N) space-separated integers (P_i\ ) denoting values of elements of the array on the first day
o Next line: An integer (Q), the number of queries
Next line: (Q) space separated integers (K_i )

Output format:
For each test case, print a single line containing (Q) space-separated integers denoting the number of ways to
pick the elements of the array in such a way that the sum of values picked is (ge K_i) .

Constraints:
(1\le T\le 10\ 1\le N\le 8\1\le Q \le 10^5\0 \le P_i \le 10^8\ 0\le k_i\ le 10^9\\)
Sample input :
1
3
3 8 10
2
13 15

Sample Output: 3 0

Explanation

For obtaining a sum of >=13, there are 3 ways

WAY 1: Pick entry 2 at day 1 at 8, entry 3 at day 2 at 10/2 and entry 1 at 3/4 8+5+0=13

WAY 2: Pick entry 3 at day 1 at 10. entry 1 at day 2 at 3/2 and entry 2 at 8/4 10+1+2=13
WAY 3: Pick entry 3 at day 1 at 10, entry 2 at day 2 at 8/2 and entry 1 at 3/4 = 10+4+0=14
There is no way of obtaining a sum of >=15
Time limit : 1sec for each input

I tried this solve it  but not getting answer

Comment: I want the algorithm for this problem statement